# character entity not showing in google search

Tags: character-encoding, google-search

I'm using   on my page, encoding is UTF-8, no BOM. Works pretty well even in other search engine, but the excerpt, Google is showing for my page contains a visible

```
&hairsp;
```

code. Is there something, I can do against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Google does not recognize the `&hairsp;` entity reference; you didn’t provide a URL, but it was rather simple to confirm the observation, searching with "hairsp" (with quotes).

The way around this bug is to use the numeric character reference `&#x200a` or the character U+200A HAIR SPACE itself.

You might also consider using other methods for creating added spacing, such as the `padding` properties in CSS. They are more flexible than the fixed-width spaces.

Comment: I often use spaces for phone numbers and stuff. It would require a lot of spans to do that with CSS. I will mark your answer as correct, but of course I will have to wait for Google to crawl the site again.

Comment: For phone numbers, you could use just normal spaces and `letter-spacing` with a negative value. Then you would need a wrapper element only for the phone number as a whole.

Comment: What I do, is for example 0171&hairsp;/&hairsp;26&thinsp;88&thinsp;67